# phpexcel File does not exist

Tags: symfony, phpexcel

I am trying to read a xlsx document with PHPExcel. My document is in my local and my code shows me this error.
*

> Could not open MunicipioPreinscripcion.xlsx for reading! File does not
>   exist.

*

This is my code (My excel document is my current directory with my controller)

```
#namespace Backend\AlumnosBundle\Controller
define('PHPEXCEL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

    $inputFileName = 'MunicipioPreinscripcion.xlsx';
    $inputFileNameWithPath = PHPEXCEL_ROOT.$inputFileName;

    if(file_exists($inputFileNameWithPath)) {
        echo 'exist'; //Allways show exist
        echo  $inputFileNameWithPath."<br>";
    } else {
        echo 'dont exist';
    }



    /**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    /**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    /**  Advise the Reader that we only want to load cell data  **/
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
     /**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName); //This is where throw the error
```

What i am doing wrong?
How can i show the directory where load() method is looking for files? I'm lost
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check permissions, try prefixing the filename with a full path

Comment: Did you succeed loading the phpexcel examples?

Comment: Yes, if you need some help you could contact with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I think it didn´t load for permission in this directory (mybundle/controller). I have moved the xlsx file to web/upload directory and this work correctly.

```
$objPHPExcel = $this->get('xls.load_xls2007')->load($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() .'/../web/upload/MunicipioPreinscripcion.xlsx');
```

Comment: what is $this in your example ?

Comment: $this is referencing the controller. This code line is in a method into a controller.